# Where to set a config option ? boot() or register() ? singleton() or bind()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

Suppose I have a `price_list` option that I set in to `null` in the `app.php` file:

```
'price_list' => null,
```

`price_list` should be set based on some conditions when my app is run. for example if logged in user has `administrator` role then I should fetch appropriate value from a `price_list` table:

```
if (Some Condition){
     $pricelist  = fetch from price_list table
     Config::set('price_list' ,$price_list);
}
```

So here, I found that to do that I should use a **service provider** and then do all those functionalities as mentioned in [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32745787/498504). But I do not know which approach is right to use **boot** or **register** method and **singleton** or **bind** method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers#the-register-method), you should never attempt to register any event listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the `register` method.
Otherwise, the `boot` fits exactly your needs, which is called after all other service providers have been registered.
so you can do something like:

```
if (\Auth::user()->isAdmin()) { //you can make the function in the model, here just an example
    config()->set('price_list', 'blablabla);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do that in the `boot()` method. From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/providers#the-boot-method):

> Within the `register` method, you should only bind things into the service container.

Also, you don't need to use `bind()` or `singleton()` methods for that. Just do this:

```
public function boot()
{
    config([price_list' => $price_list]);
}
```

Comment: May I have similar need to define new options in Continued development.Is it necessary to define separate serviceProvider for each them?

Comment: @A.B.Developer if you're going to override more configs in the future, it's a good idea to define a separate service provider for this (one provider for all `config()` clauses).