# How can I solve global variable declaration in Laravel function not normal PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, scope, global-variables, dynamic-variables

this is my code and it works quite well in **normal PHP** but not working in **Laravel helpers.php file**

```
$t = [13];
function subtraction()
{
    global $t;
    $t[] = 14;
    var_dump($t,gettype($t));
} 
subtraction();
```

result in **normal PHP file** is :

```
array:2 [
  0 => 13
  1 => 14
]
"array"
```

result in **Laravel** is :

```
array:1 [
  0 => 14
]
"array"
```

I hope help me...
Thanks

Comment: How are you including that helper file? The use of `global` is sometimes a sign of code smell. There is probably a better way to do what you're doing. Perhaps take a step back and tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @pichanakian what are you trying to achieve ? Using `global` in Laravel is a no-no, you are doing something wrong. When using Laravel forget about `$_GLOBAL` or `$_POST` or anything similar. You have to use the framework to solve this. Could you explain more why are you trying to use `global` like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare any global variable in .env file while using laravel. e.g

```
GLOBAL_T = 13;
```

And you can call it in helper file like this:

```
env('GLOBAL_T');
```

If you want to define an array as global then please visit this link answer is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854030/laravel-where-to-store-global-arrays-data-and-constants)

Comment: A config file would be better suited for this, assuming the GLOBAL_T doesn't change in a different **env**ironment.

Comment: @brombeer @kaleemshoukat a `config` file is **MANDATORY** as when you are on `production`, `env()` does not work anymore once config is cached...