# Declaring Globally Accessible Variable in Laravel in the Config Folder that is available in all Views and Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, global-variables

I read the question

[global variable for all controller and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views)

It tells about declaring a variable in the filters.php in the root folder, (Thought it was said it is not a good practice to declare in the filters.php file )I tried but didn't succeed.  But i need to declare a variable in any file of the config folder that should be available to all controllers and views.

Where should i do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a PHP file inside app/config folder

For example:
Create app/config/settings.php

Inside this settings.php:

```
<?php
     return array(
                 'LANGUAGE_ID' => 1,
                 'DATE_FORMAT' => 'Y-m-d'
            );
```

And you can access this in views and controllers using:

```
Config::get('settings.LANGUAGE_ID');
```

If you will create different environment, you need to put the newly created config file to each environment folder.