# How to determine global variable in Blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I try to determine a global variable in template blade:

```
global $result_view;
```

Below this I try call this:

```
 <?=$result_view?>
```

And get error: `Undefined variable: result_view ()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - global Blade view variable available in all templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates)

Comment: By global, do you mean that the variable should be available for all blade templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Controller or Service provider , you can add

```
View::share('result_view', 'SomeValue');
```

in any **Blade** template in your project you can use,

```
{{ $result_view }}
```

Comment: Becareful when using this with wildcards like View::share('folder.*') especially when your variable is retrieving from a database query. Every blade file being included or rendered makes 1 extra query and ends up making tons of the same query per blade file.

Comment: very important note from @BillL.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to define your variable in a config file and then you'll be able to get this var in all views, controllers etc.

```
{{ config('myConfig.someVariable') }}
```

Also, you can use [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) to set global variable.

Comment: No, this variable will not available inside function in template

Comment: You're right. Then you got two options: using `config()` method and using view composer.