# Making object accessible throughout application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am adding user notifications to my system.  To access these notifications for a user, I call an API I have created in another system.  So, my IndexController looks something like the following

```
public function index()
{
    if ($user = Sentinel::getUser()) {
        $notifications = MyAPI::returnNotifications($user->id);
        return view('centaur.dashboard', compact('notifications'));
    }
}
```

Now to problem with the above is that notifications is now only available on the dashboard view.  Within my header view I have something like this

```
@if($notifications)
    @foreach($notifications as $notification)
        <a class="content" href="#">

            <div class="notification-item">
                <h4 class="item-title">{{ $notification->subject }}</h4>
                <p class="item-info">{{ $notification->body }}</p>
            </div>

        </a>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

But if I now visit another page besides the dashboard page I get a Undefined variable: notifications error.  This is because header is on every page, but I am only passing my notification object to the dashboard page.

Is there any way to make this notification object universally available?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
if($user = Sentinel::getUser()) {
    view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
        $view->with('notifications', MyAPI::returnNotifications($user->id));
    });
}
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers). In your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider@boot` method add:

```
view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
    $view->with('notifications', MyAPI::returnNotifications($user->id););
});
```

Now you'll have the variable `$notifications` in all of your views. If you want it for specific ones just replace the `*` with the view name.

Comment: That looks like the type of solution I need.  One question though, how do I get the user to this boot function?  Even if I get the current user, it does not seem to like it even if I do what I have updated the OP with.