# Laravel Blade - Pass Data to layout without using it in every Public Function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my Laravel Blade Layout I created files for the header, navigation, footer, etc.
Those Files have been `@include()`d into a layout file, which has a `yield('content')`.

Now, I want to show for example a product in a view. The view however uses the `nav.blade.php`, which shows categories (loading from the db).

When sending my `product` data to my view, I get an error, because the nav has no data about `categories`:

```
Undefined variable: categories
```

Is there a possibility to give the nav the data without sending it with every view?

My `public function` for the product page currently looks like this:

```
$product = Product::findOrFail($id);
return view('product.single')->with('product', $product);
```

In order to work it should also send this with it:

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategories.products.prices', 'subcategories.products.image')->get();
```

But i don't want to send that with every view.

Comment: If you're not morally against bad code you can just add that line of code in the view where needed.

Comment: maybe you can use view composer for that. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Answer (score 2):

read about [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers):

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view
>   each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize
>   that logic into a single location.