# How to use @include with variables in blade in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5.3

list.blade.php

```
<?php
$categories=[
'1'=>'cat1',
'2'=>'cat2',
'3'=>'cat3',
    ];
?>
```

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@include('partials.list')


<?php 
  foreach($categories as $key => $value) 
  { 
     echo "$value <br />"; 
  } 
?>  

@endsection
```

How to use $categories in index.blade.php? Why @include('partials.list') is not working? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Comment: So, are you not able to include the "partials/list.blade.php" into "index.blade.php" OR yu are just not able to get that $categories vaiable into "index.blade.php"?