# Generate differents menus on login

Tags: laravel

I need to generate differents menus for my application when login depending on the user role. In order to do this, I need to extract some information from database.

I think the better solution is to code after login the generation of html for the menu and save it on a session variable. Then in my layout i only have to put that session variable and don't have to repeat all the code in all pages.

Am I right?

Where is the better place for coding this?

Thanks!

Comment: try this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Comment: put the menus in a separate folder and include them as per the users. Like if app()->user->isBlaBla then  include('balbla-menu') or use a switch statement.

Comment: Two interesting approach. I will check both. Thanks!