# laravel share view variables only if view extend specific layout

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple layouts for the project.

So I'm calling a different layout base on the view requested.

I want to share a variables to a specific layout, and other variables for another one, and so on ..

i.e:

in layouts folder:

1- app.blade

2- base.blade

3- project1.blade

I want to share data to the layouts, without having to hard code these data every time I call a view in the controller:

if any view extend app.blade, then data1 is shared

if any view extend base.blade, then data2 is shared, and so on ..

is there an easy way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is this data static? if it is you could use .env vars

Comment: also have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates ? it might be a good start

Comment: Take a look at [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function

In AppserviceProvider.php file boot function

```
view()->composer(['articles.index', 'articles.show', 'blog.*'], function ($view) {
    $view->with('total', $total);
});
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.