# How to pass Eloquent Data to blade component?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, components, laravel-blade

**Hello**,

I have a blade Layout called: 
**`profile.blade.php`** // component

And I have a blade file **infos** which extends from `profile.blade.php` component.
On my controller, I have a profile method:

```
public method profile(User $user) {
   return view('infos.blade.php', compact('user'));
}
```

When I try to use the variable **user** to the **profile.blade.php componen**t, I have an error that says "**undefined user variable**"

My question is how can I get the data I received from my controller to **Blade Component profle** ?
Because that part of component will be used many times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

in your app/view/components/profile-

```
  <?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class profile extends Component
{

   public $user; //for consistency

   public function __construct($user)
   {
       $this->user = $user;
   }


   public function render()
   {
       return view('components.profile');
   }
 }
```

now the component can render a variable ($user),
in your info's blade/infos.blade.php you can feed the
variable to the component like --

```
<x-profile :user='$user' ></x-profile>
```

i understand the question was posted quite a long ago
but i had the same issue and the answers posted here
didn't work for me but this method did so.....it may help somebody.

Comment: Make sure you use single quotes around your variable, not double quotes!

Answer (score 1):

As it's a component you have to pass user parameter each time you call it, for example

```
@component('profile', ['user' => $user]) @endcomponent // here $user comes from controller
```

Comment: that is one way to but I'm looking for something like make it global.

Comment: then use `@include`, not `@component`

Comment: if you look global variable laravel provide something call `view-composer` you can check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers

Comment: some question about how to make global variable also has been post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Comment: View composer it is. Thanks for the tip.