# Access php variable defined in master blade in other blades where master blade is extended . PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a laravel PHP project and I have a global blade where I have defined a variable

```
<?php
    $a = "some value fetched dynamically";
?>
```

And I am extending this blade in over 100 blade files like this

```
@extends('global')
```

In all these blades how can I access this $a variable?

Versions - PHP 7.2.34, Laravel 5.3.31

Thanks in advance.

PS: if there is any other way where I can get the PHP variable/function defined in the global blade in other blades please feel free to suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5 - global Blade view variable available in all templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose blade or layout you are importing in every blade and add this code

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

public function register()
{
  // the layout you want, You can add '*' instead of 'blade' for all views
  \View::composer('blade', function ($view) {
     $value = "Data"
     $view->with('value', $value);
  });
}
```

At the blade use it like a normal variable.

---

Also, you can do it in another way Laravel [composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers)