# Laravel 8 – Blade template – read variable from another template file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

This must be really simple, but since I’m new to Laravel, I’m having difficulties on finding this feature on documentation or in stackoverflow.

I’m going to try to build a very simple example to try to show what I want.

Let’s say I have a file called data.blade.php

```
@php
$myVariable = 'xyz';
@endphp
```

Then, I have my layout template file, called: home.blade.php

```
@extends('data.blade')
@section('content')
    @php
        echo $myVariable;
    @endphp
@endsection
```

When I try to do this, it returns me an error:

```
Undefined variable $myVariable (etc)
```

How can I use a variable defined in another blade file? I used extends to exemplify, but I´m not sure if that is the right architecture.

Can anyone point me to the right way of accomplishing this?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Comment: Trying out one of the solutions. Seems that the first one is working fine for what I´m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you are extending data.blade.php and this file need to have some element to serve as template and be extended.

You can take any html5 file and rename this as template.blade.php, but where you want to render a section in your template must have a yield('section-name').

Make a new  app.blade.php should look like this

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show
 
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
 
@section('title', 'Page Title')
 
@section('sidebar')
    @parent
 
    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@endsection
 

@section('content')
  @include(data)
   {{$myVariable}}


    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

[From Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#layouts-using-template-inheritance)

Comment: Again - I´m new to laravel, so be patient with my questions. ```@include``` can only be used inside ```@section```? Because, in my case, I would need to move ```@include``` to before the ```@extends('layout')``` in order to accomplish what I´m searching for. And also have the ability to use the variable defined inside ```@include``` anywhere in the template file.

Comment: You can use include anywhere below extend, but will be displayed in yield content conveniently.

Comment: And how about before ```@extends```? Any other mechanism I could use to access that data variable?

Comment: If you want to pass some data to a view you will, almost always do via an array from the view.

Comment: myControllerMethod()
{
    return view('myview',['myVar'=>'Test'])
}

Comment: It´s an interesting approach, but not exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What are you looking for? What is your prob?

Comment: Well, I need a way that I could print a variable that should be defined in ````data.blade.php file```, but that would come before any info in my file - even before ````@extends('layouts.app')```.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245330/discussion-between-manuel-glez-and-jorge-mauricio).