# Editable global site settings in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to store global settings in the database, that then will be editable from cPanel. I have a model `Setting`, which has only 1 item with multiple columns such as `siteName`, `language`, `siteDescription` and etc. I want to make these accessible in every view, so do I need to do

`$settings = \MyApp\Setting::find(1);`

for every single controller? Is there a way to define this variable somewhere globally and have it accessible in every single controller / view ?

Or perhaps this is not the correct way to do it?

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views

Comment: You can add `view()->share('settings', $settings);` to your base controller or a service provider but since I'm sure you will not need the settings in every single view I think the best approach would be to use a wildcard view composer http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's better to write that code snippet into BaseController.

or

Create a trait and write into it. use that trait in anywhere you want.

Comment: Yes, probably that's what I will do. Or use the share() functionality from ServiceProvider.