# Make variable accesible to whole Laravel 5.2 application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently developing a Web Application using Laravel 5.2, in the database I have some configurations saved, I use that Settings along a lot of controllers in the application, so I don't want to be consulting over and over again the same thing.
I want to consult it only on application boot, and it this way also reduce the code and no be repetitive. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views) but it seems like are old answers to old versions of the framework.
So, In Laravel 5.2 how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views) in your question, there the answers were given for Laravel 4.x and if you want to implement the same technique in version 5.2 and later then you can use a global middleware. To do that, just create a middleware from your terminal using something like the following:

```
php artisan make:middleware GlobalConfigMiddleware
```

This'll create a middleware (`GlobalConfigMiddleware.php`) in your `app/Http/Middleware` directory. In this file, all you need to implement the logic for setting up the config within the `handle` method which should look something like the following:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // Pseudo Code
    app()->singleton('site_settings', function($app) {
        // Imagine you have the Setting Eloquent Model
        // Get all settings using the Setting model
        return \App\Setting::all();
    });

    // If you use this line of code then it'll be available in any view
    // as $site_settings but you may also use app('site_settings') as well
    view()->share('site_settings', app('site_settings'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

Then, add this middleware class in the `$middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class, for example:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \App\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfigMiddleware::class,
];
```

Now, you can use the config like this:

```
$site_settings = app('site_settings');
```

Learn about [Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#global-middleware) and [Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/container#binding). Also remember that, this could be done in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `config` [helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-config) and set some custom config variable

**Set a config var**

```
config(['app.yourvar' => 'IlikeCookies']);
```

**Get a config var**

```
$value = config('app.yourvar', 'fallback');
```

If you want it to run on boot, you can use a `ServiceProvider`

and fill the config in the [boot()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#the-boot-method) function.

Comment: ok, and where should I load the value of that variable?I have all the values in the database. That seems to be used to static values