# How to make a variable accessable to the whole controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Lets say I have a

### IndexController

Which contains a function

```
public function store($store)
{
    $store = (query)->get();
    return $store;
}
```

Now I want one column from `store` to be accessible to all functions like

```
$id = $store->id
```

I want it to be usable like this

```
public function abv()
{
    $categories = (query)->where('id','=',$id)->get();
}
```

My point is that it becomes a global variable to the whole controller. How do I achieve this?

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this value in the constructor of your controller as a private property.

```
class MyController {
    private $id;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->id = (query)->get();
    }

    // More controller functions
}
```

Now any function in your controller will be able to call this property using `$this->id`.

Comment: How can I pass variable to __construct?

Comment: Normally you should do this when creating the object. However, with Laravel controllers this is not possible as far as I know. Maybe through injection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but you can declare a protected or public variable in your Controller `protected $id`, then when you call store

```
public function store($store)
{
   $store = (query)->get();
   $this->id = $store->id;
   return $store;
}
```

And to use in other functions:

```
public function abv()
{
  $categories = (query)->where('id','=',$this->id)->get();
}
```

But this is only avaiable for the same instance of Controller, if you create a new instace of your Controller the variable $id will not be set until you call store method.

Comment: This seems pretty easy without changing much of the code!