# Set Global Variable accessible in all controller methods Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, global-variables, laravel-5.3

I have this route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'returnphase'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@home')->name('homepage');
});
```

My middleware check in what Phase (logic is non important now) is my application, i need that the controller setting up a global variable that i can use in all methods inside FrontendController because i need to read from database some data that depend from that check:

Middleware code, i need to set a phase_id varibale that i can use in may frontend controller.

```
namespace Cbcc\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ReturnPhaseMiddleware
{


    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        /**
         * TODO: Phase id check logic
         */

        // SETTING GLOBAL PHASE ID VARIABLE (EXAMPLE PHASE_ID = 1)

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

My frontend controller

```
//FrontEndController

namespace Cbcc\Http\Controllers;

use Cbcc\Page;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{

    public function home()
    {


        $page = Page::where([
            ['phase_id',/**** I NEED GLOBAL PHASE ID  HERE SETTING BY MIDDLEWARE***/],
            ['type','home']
        ])->get()[0];

        return view('frontend.index',compact('page'));
    }

}
```

Any ideas to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [global variable for all controller and views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views)

Comment: Why don't you use a define? Eg. define('MY_VAR', $val); and use it as echo MY_VAR

Answer (score 0):

You might want to user Session variables. What about using flash session variables since it seems you only use this variable once :

**Middleware**

```
class ReturnPhaseMiddleware
{


    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        /**
         * TODO: Phase id check logic
         */

        $request->session()->flash('PHASE_ID', '1');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Front-end controller**

```
class FrontendController extends Controller
{

    public function home(Request $request)
    {


        $page = Page::where([
            ['phase_id', $request->session()->get('PHASE_Id')],
            ['type','home']
        ])->get()[0];

        return view('frontend.index',compact('page'));
    }
}
```

The special property of flash session variables is that they get destroyed at the next request.

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#flash-data

Comment: \Session::get('PHASE_ID') ?

Comment: check my solution without session, what do you think about?

Answer (score 0):

Good strategy, and without using session?

What do you think about my solution?

```
// Frontend Controlller
namespace Cbcc\Http\Controllers;

use Cbcc\Lib\CheckPhaseInterface;
use Cbcc\Page;

class FrontendController extends Controller
{


    protected
        $phase_id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {


// this 2 lines return phase id logic, for example $check->run() return 1 (int)
            $check = resolve(CheckPhaseInterface::class);

            $this->phase_id = $check->run();

            return $next($request);
        });
    }

    public function home()
    {
        $page = $this->getPageContent();
        return view('frontend.index',compact('page'));
    }


    protected function getPageContent()
    {
        return Page::where([
            ['phase_id',$this->phase_id],
            ['type','home']
        ])->get()[0];
    }

}
```