# How to set Global variable in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set a global variable in Laravel, I set in `__construct()` function but can not use this outside of controller.
Where should I set that variable?

```
public function __construct()
{
    $cat = Categories::get()->first();
}
```

but I can't access the `$cat` variable in some pages.

Comment: Do you want to be able to access `$cat` across views?

Comment: You may check this answer: [global variable for all controller and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views)

Comment: You may want to look at Laravel's View Composers to share data across all views. (https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to access `$cat` variable everywhere i.e in all controllers and views you should share it as below:

```
protected $cat;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->cat = Categories::get()->first();
    View::share('site_settings', $this->cat);
}
```

I will assume that you are using `BaseController` constructor. Now if your controllers extend this `BaseController`, they can just access the category using `$this->cat`.

**Second Method:**

You can also give a try using Config class. All you need to do is add the following code within `boot` method of `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
Config::set(['user' => ['name' => 'John Doe']]);
```

Then any where in your project you can fetch the value by using `Config::get('user.name');`

Answer (score 6):

Use service providers

https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-5-global-variable-in-all-views-file

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{

    /**

     * Bootstrap any application services.

     *

     * @return void

     */

    public function boot()

    {

        view()->share('siteTitle', 'HDTuto.com');



    }

    /**

     * Register any application services.

     *

     * @return void

     */

    public function register()

    {

        //

    }

}
```

and in your view

```
{{ $siteTitle }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use solution, which is as given below:

```
App::before(function($request) {
    App::singleton('cat', function(){
        return Categories::get()->first();
    });
});
```

Now to get data in controller using below line;

```
$cat = app('cat');
```

and you can pass data in view using below line:

```
view('home', compact('cat'));
```