# Laravel Global Variable to specific views

Tags: laravel-5

I would like assistance with calling a global variable on Laravel app for specific pages or routes.

This is my current code which works on login

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```php
public function boot()
{
   view()->composer(['auth.login'], function ($view) {
      $view->with('settings', AppSetting::where('id',1)->first());
   });
}
```

This is the route for the login page

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```

**[Edit 1]**

On the login page , I used this code bellow to get the app version

```php
{{$settings->app_version}}
```

[image: example]

Comment: which global variable you want use?

Comment: On my login blade view , I am using ```{{$settings->app_version}}``` to show the app name from saved db values which are on **app_settings** table.


Initially, I had 

```
 view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $view->with('settings', AppSetting::where('id',1)->first());
        });

```

Which was loading everywhere but that is giving me too many duplicate queries in some areas where I have many models in on Controller.

So, I want it to be only available on specific views or models.

Comment: try to clarify your question by adding an example

Comment: why do you need to store your version in database?

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little I think a good solution might be caching your ***AppSetting*** Model.

Write the given code in **App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{


   /**
   * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
   *
   * @return void
   */
   public function boot()
   {
      parent::boot();
      App::before(function($request) {
           App::singleton('settings', function(){
             return AppSetting::where('id',1)->first();
           });

       // If you use this line of code then it'll be available in any view
       // as $settings but you may also use app('settings') as well
       View::share('settings', app('settings'));
     });
   }
}
```

`App::singleton` will call once `AppSetting::where('id',1)->first()` and after one call your `settings` will be cached.

And you can use `{{$settings->app_version}}` in your view.

**Reference: [stackoverflow.com/a/25190686/7047493](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25190686/7047493)**