# Two types of likes with Cookie

Tags: laravel

I need any user to be able to like it every 24 hours

I wrote a function for this

```
const LIKE_HEART = 'like_heart';
const LIKE_FINGER = 'like_finger';
public static $types = [self::LIKE_HEART, self::LIKE_FINGER];

public function setLikes() {
$likes = Cookie::get($types);
$hours = 24;
    if ($likes) {
       self::where('id', $article->id)
       ->where('updated_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subHours($hours))
       ->increment($types);
}
}
```

But I have two fields in my database, `like_heart` and `like_finger`, these should be two types of likes. How can I rewrite my function into a method so that I can only choose one type of like out of two?

An array of the following type must be serialized in cookies:

```
$r = [
    '1' => [
        'like_heart' => '2021-09-28 22:02:01',
        'like_finger' => '2021-11-28 11:12:34',
    ],
    '2' => [
        'like_finger' => '2021-11-28 11:12:34',
    ],
];
```

where 1, 2 is the article ID. Date - the date the like was added by current users
The current date is compared with the date in this cookie for a specific article, and if it is less than 24 hours old or missing, add +1 to the corresponding like in the article and add / change information in the like.

article.blade

```
<div class="blog-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="article">
                <p><b>{!! $article->title !!}</b></p>
                <p><b>{!! $article->subtitle !!}</b></p>
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="{{ $article->image_list_mobile }}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{{ $article->image_mobile_alt }}" title="{{ $article->image_mobile_title }}">
                    <source srcset="{{ $article->image_list }}" alt="{{ $article->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article->image_title }}">
                    <img srcset="{{ $article->image_list }}" alt="{{ $article->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article->image_title }}">
                </picture>
                <p><b>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article->published_at)) }}</b></p>
                <p><b>{{ $article->getTotalViews() }} Views</b></p>
                <p><b>{{ $allArticleCommentsCount }} Comments</b></p>
            </div>

            <a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}/like?type=like_heart" class="btn btn-primary">Like Heart</a>
            <a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}/like?type=like_finger" class="btn btn-primary">Like Finger</a>

            <div class="comments">
                <div class="recommend-title"><p><b>Comments ({{ $allArticleCommentsCount }})</b></p></div>
                @foreach($article_comments as $article_comment)
                    <p><b>{!! $article_comment->name !!}</b></p>
                    <p><b>{!! $article_comment->text !!}</b></p>
                    <p><b>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article_comment->date)) }}</b></p>
                @endforeach
            </div>

            
        </div>
    </div>
```

controller

```
public function index(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if(!$article){
            return abort(404);
        }
        
        $viewed = Session::get('viewed_article', []);
        if (!in_array($article->id, $viewed)) {
            $article->increment('views');
            Session::push('viewed_article', $article->id);
        }

        $allArticleCommentsCount = ArticleComment::where('article_id', $article->id)->count();

        $article_comments = ArticleComment::where('article_id', $article->id)->get();

        return view('article', compact('article', 'article_comments', 'allArticleCommentsCount'));
    }

public function postLike() {
        if ($like = request('like')) {
            $articleId = request('article_id');
    
            if (User::hasLikedToday($articleId, $like)) {
                return response()
                    ->json([
                        'message' => 'You have already liked the Article #'.$articleId.' with '.$like.'.',
                    ]);
            }
    
            $cookie = User::setLikeCookie($articleId, $like);
    
            return response()
                ->json([
                    'message' => 'Liked the Article #'.$articleId.' with '.$like.'.',
                    'cookie_json' => $cookie->getValue(),
                ])
                ->withCookie($cookie);
        }
    }
```

Article model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public static function hasLikedToday($articleId, string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Check if there are any likes for this article
        if (! array_key_exists($articleId, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if there are any likes with the given type
        if (! array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$articleId])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$articleId][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public static function setLikeCookie($articleId, string $type)
    {
        // Initialize the cookie default
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Update the selected articles type
        $articleLikes[$articleId][$type] = today()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::get('/article', function () {
    $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

    return view('article')->with([
        'articleLikesJson' => $articleLikesJson,
    ]);
});

Route::get('article/{id}/like', 'App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController@postLike');
```

Comment: Hi...read this thread here on stack [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189427/global-variable-for-all-controller-and-views)

Comment: "How can I rewrite my function into a method so that I can only choose one type of like out of two?" seems confusing to me, as your current function only handles one type of like and you are talking about it as it handles two?

Comment: Can you be more clear with what you are trying to achieve?  Do you want each user to be able to 'heart' or 'finger' only **one** post 24h?  Or  'heart' or 'finger' **each** post once in 24h?

Comment: @Rory yes, I want any user every 24 hours to be able to add a finger or a heart to each article, and that the number of likes is added to the database

Comment: @Rory I added to my post how I roughly see the situation

Comment: @mrhn updated post

Comment: added more detailed information about what I need

Comment: Is there any reason for doing this in cookies, compared to doing it in the backend only?

Comment: @mrhn did not understand the question a little

Comment: I need to use cookies

Comment: Why do you need to use cookies?

Comment: @mrhn It's more convenient for me to store all this data in cookies, I don't see any other options. is it possible to implement in cookies what I added to the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should never store any logic in the client side. A great alternative for this kind of feature would be using the Laravel Aquantances package.

https://laravel-news.com/manage-friendships-likes-and-more-with-the-acquaintances-laravel-package

Anyway, since you want to do it with cookies;

We can actually do this a lot easier than thought.

Articles.php

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public static function hasLikedToday($articleId, string $type)
    {
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Check if there are any likes for this article
        if (! array_key_exists($articleId, $articleLikes)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Check if there are any likes with the given type
        if (! array_key_exists($type, $articleLikes[$articleId])) {
            return false;
        }

        $likeDatetime = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $articleLikes[$articleId][$type]);

        return ! $likeDatetime->addDay()->lt(now());
    }

    public static function setLikeCookie($articleId, string $type)
    {
        // Initialize the cookie default
        $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '[]');

        $articleLikes = json_decode($articleLikesJson, true);

        // Update the selected articles type
        $articleLikes[$articleId][$type] = today()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $articleLikesJson = json_encode($articleLikes);

        return cookie()->forever('article_likes', $articleLikesJson);
    }
}
```

The code above will allow us to is a user has liked an article and generate the cookie we want to set.

There are a couple important things you need to care about.

- Not forgetting to send the cookie with the response.
- Redirecting back to a page so that the cookies take effect.

I've made a very small example:

routes/web.php

```php
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $articleLikesJson = \Cookie::get('article_likes', '{}');

    if ($like = request('like')) {
        $articleId = request('article_id');

        if (User::hasLikedToday($articleId, $like)) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with([
                    'success' => 'You have already liked the Article #'.$articleId.' with '.$like.'.',
                ]);
        }

        $cookie = User::setLikeCookie($articleId, $like);

        return redirect()->back()
            ->withCookie($cookie)
            ->with([
                'success' => 'Liked the Article #'.$articleId.' with '.$like.'.',
            ]);
    }

    return view('test')->with([
        'articleLikesJson' => $articleLikesJson,
    ]);
});
```

resources/views/test.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        @if (session('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                {{ session('success') }}
            </div>
        @endif

        <pre>{{ $articleLikesJson }}</pre>

        <div class="row">
            @foreach (range(1, 4) as $i)
                <div class="col-3">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Article #{{  $i }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                            <a href="/test?like=heart&article_id={{ $i }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Like Heart
                            </a>
                            <a href="/test?like=finger&article_id={{ $i }}" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Like Finger
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                            2 days ago
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Post Update:

1- Remove the range()

2- Update the route of these links (to where you put the logic for liking)

3- Below I've added an example for route `Route::post('article/{id}/like', [SomeController::class, 'postLike'])`

```html
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}/like?type=heart" class="btn btn-primary">Like Heart</a>
<a href="/article/{{ $article->id }}/like?type=finger" class="btn btn-primary">Like Finger</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try to do it at my place)

Comment: As far as I understand, in your example, only registered users can put likes, or anyone?

Comment: No, I only used the User model as a place to hold the logic. Since it's cookie based, anybody can do it.

Comment: ok, got it, thanks)

Comment: Another question, I have a separate page for each article, and in the route it looks like `/blog/{slug}` (article slug field), how can I apply this to this example?

Comment: Cookies are domain based not URL, you won't have to change anything, I've also updated your other questions answer to use AJAX. So that you don't have to reload the page every time you like something. Have a look there.

Comment: and probably the last question, 4 such buttons appeared on my page, apparently due to the fact that I specify range (1, 4) in foreach

Comment: Yes, that was for my article testing, you willbe having only 1 pair on your page, since the page will contain only 1 article.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is still a question, I have a page article.blade.php, according to your example, instead of a test I take my article page, added routes

Comment: I also have a controller where I end up using return view ('article', compact ('article')); , and now when I click like I have disagreements, I get this error Possible typo $article
Did you mean $articleLikesJson?

Comment: I have data like $article->title on my page

Comment: SomeController is my article controller as I understand it?

Comment: Yes, lets continue chat here: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1616/ozans-room

Comment: sorry, I can't write in that chat, I don't have enough reputation

Comment: now it turns out that my controller does not have such a postLike method

Comment: Yep, you can simply copy the content of my `Route::post('test'...` to your controller and update the parameters.

Comment: So, I figured it out, but this is for the `post`, but for the `get` the same thing to do, what should be there?

Comment: get is where you show your page, you don't do anything there. When you click on the button it loads the `/article/{id}/postLike` page, process the like logic and redirect the user back to your `/article/{slug}`

Comment: now my get looks like this `Route::get('/article'...` and `return view('article')...` 
and i get the error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: and if so `Route::get('/article/{id}/like...` and `return view('article')...` I get the same as before `Possible typo $article
Did you mean $articleLikesJson?`

Comment: `GET /article/{id}/like`, won't return view, it will only increment the database count, set the cookie and redirect. You can see the examples from the answer. `GET /article/{slug}` will return the view.

Comment: i dont know i get error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` and all this because of this `Route::post('article/{id}/like', [ArticleController::class, 'postLike'])`

Comment: `Route::post` means only post `Route::get` means get, you can only `POST` with ajax. If you use normal `<a>` tag, it must be `Route::get`

Comment: okay, did so `Route::get('article/{id}/like', [ArticleController::class, 'postLike'])` no errors, now just go to the blank page `article/1/like?type=like_heart`, but +1 like was not added to the database

Comment: Did you add the `if ($like = request('like')) { ... }` part from the answer there?

Comment: yes, I created `public function postLike()` and added everything I needed in the controller

Comment: It's better to contact from some place we can screen share.

Comment: I added to the post all the code that I use for this task, maybe the like_heart and like_finger fields just don't reach?

Comment: Can you update `postLike` in your question?

Comment: I did not understand a bit what to update, I added all the content that was necessary to `postLike()`

Comment: it is there below in the controller

Comment: okay so, what you're missing is: 

After this line: `$cookie = User::setLikeCookie($articleId, $like)` you must update the database.

Comment: what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Just add your database query after that line and its all good.

Comment: like so? `$articles = DB::table('articles')->get();` but nothing has changed

Comment: No no, just like you did before... `Article::where('id', $id)->increment('like_'.$type);`

Comment: nothing changes, in the same place, in theory, the message should still be displayed, but I just have an empty page coming out

Comment: and `article_likes` is also not shown in the cookie

Comment: https://codeshare.io/6px8AO

Comment: now problems with parameters, does not see the User class, neither $articleId, nor $like

Comment: I've updated the variable names again, have a look. Don't forget to import the User class on top so that the code finds it.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot) the rest is super last question

Comment: why the time is not fully displayed? Here, in the hasLikedToday function, I have $likeDatetime and in the end it only shows Y-m-d and H:i:s are shown as 00:00:00

Comment: You can use `now()`, instead of `today()`

Comment: Hey are you here?